# question related to Lipschitz continuous function

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions, bounded-variation, absolute-continuity

Here I am writing what i understood the Lipschitz continuity of a function. Given a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ defined from a metric space $(X, d_X) $ to a metric space $(Y, d_Y)$ is said to be a Lipschitz continuous function, if there exists at least one real constant $k$ such that $d_Y(f(x_1), f(x_2))\leq k d_X(x_1, x_2),$ $\forall x_1, x_2\in X.$ My questions are 
(1) Can $k$ may be zero?
(2) If there exists more than one $k$ satisfying the above inequality, then which one is a Lipschitz constant?
(3) Relation between the Lipschitz continuity of a function, uniform continuity of a function, absolute continuity of a function, differentiability of a function and a function of a bounded variation, boundedness of a function. Here my function $f$ should be defined on any metric space $X$ to $Y$

Comment: If $k=0$ then $f$ is constant. And if $k$ is a Lipschitz constant for $f$, then so is $k^{\prime}$ for any $k^{\prime}\geq k$.

Comment: So constant function can be considered as Lipschitz continuous function?

Comment: Yes, since then $d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2))=0$ for all $x_1,x_2$. Of course this case isn't especially interesting.

Comment: Which one is the best Lipschitz constant? the smallest of all such $k\geq 0?$

Answer (score 1):

The other questions have been addressed by comments, so I will only address part (3).  Indeed, these relations are addressed by the [Wikipedia page for Lipschitz continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity). I only want to draw your attention to the fact to the following result:

If $f$ is Lipschitz continuous then it is differentiable *almost everywhere.*

This general result is known as [Rademacher's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem).

Comment: this theorem holds for the functions which are defined from Euclidean metric space into arbitrary metric space. But i want for a general metric space

Comment: further in wikipedia details about all such relations are given for Euclidean metric space